# Printing a Response To A Partially Completed Python Async Event Loop While Still Completing The Task After The Response

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm working with Sanic, but I'm a bit stuck. I'm calling on 3 different API's each having their own response time.

I want to create a timeout function that provides a acceptable time for each task to return. But if the time task isn't complete within the acceptable time I want to return partial data as I don't need a complete data set and speed is more of a focus.

However, i want to keep the unfinished task working until completion (ie. requesting the API data and inserting into a Postgres DB.

I'm wondering if we can do this without using some kind of scheduler to keep the task running within the background.

Comment: Are you familiar with the listener/observer pattern? It's often used with asynchronous callbacks that can return at any point

Comment: No, but do you have any links?

Comment: Googling `Python Observer Pattern` comes up with this: http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=5117. Otherwise just poke around for a tutorial that helps you

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it now and report back

Comment: Using streaming HTTP requests or web sockets you can return a response at any time and keep that process running.

Answer (score 2):

> But if the time task isn't complete within the acceptable time I want
>   to return partial data as I don't need a complete data set and speed
>   is more of a focus.
>
> However, i want to keep the unfinished task working until completion

So other tasks are independent from timeouted task's state, right? If I understood you correctly you just want to run 3 `asyncio.Task` with their own timeouts and to aggregate their results at the end.

Only possible problem I see is "want to return partial data" since it may very vary on how things organized, but we can probably just pass this "partial data" with cancelled exception raised inside task on timeout.

Here's little prototype:

```
import asyncio


class PartialData(Exception):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data        


async def api_job(i):
    data = 'job {i}:'.format(i=i)
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        data += ' step 1,'
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        data += ' step 2,'
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        data += ' step 3.'
    except asyncio.CancelledError as exc:
        raise PartialData(data)  # Pass partial data to outer code with our exception.
    else:
        return data


async def api_task(i, timeout):
    """Wrapper for api_job to run it with timeout and retrieve it's partial data on timeout."""
    t = asyncio.ensure_future(api_job(i))
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(t, timeout)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        try:
            await t
        except PartialData as exc:
            return exc.data  # retrieve partial data on timeout and return it.
    else:
        return t.result()


async def main():
    # Run 3 jobs with different timeouts:
    results = await asyncio.gather(
        api_task(1, timeout=2), 
        api_task(2, timeout=4), 
        api_task(3, timeout=6),
    )

    # Print results including "partial data":
    for res in results:
        print(res)


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()
```

**Output:**

```
job 1: step 1,
job 2: step 1, step 2,
job 3: step 1, step 2, step 3.
```

(as you can see first two jobs finished with timeouts and only part of their's datas retrieved)

**Upd:**

Complex example contain possible solutions to different events:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress


async def stock1(_):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 'stock1 res'

async def stock2(exception_in_2):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if exception_in_2:
        raise ValueError('Exception in stock2!')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 'stock2 res'

async def stock3(_):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return 'stock3 res'


async def main():
    # Vary this values to see different situations:
    timeout = 2.5
    exception_in_2 = False


    # To run all three stocks just create tasks for them:
    tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(s(exception_in_2)) 
        for s 
        in (stock1, stock2, stock3)
    ]


    # Now we just wait until one of this possible situations happened:
    # 1) Everything done
    # 2) Exception occured in one of tasks
    # 3) Timeout occured and at least two tasks ready
    # 4) Timeout occured and less than two tasks ready
    # ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait )
    await asyncio.wait(
        tasks, 
        timeout=timeout, 
        return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION
    )

    is_success = all(t.done() and not t.exception() for t in tasks)
    is_exception = any(t.done() and t.exception() for t in tasks)
    is_good_timeout = \
        not is_success and \
        not is_exception and \
        sum(t.done() for t in tasks) >= 2
    is_bad_timeout = \
        not is_success and \
        not is_exception and \
        sum(t.done() for t in tasks) < 2


    # If success, just print all results:
    if is_success:
        print('All done before timeout:')
        for t in tasks:
            print(t.result())
    # If timeout, but at least two done,
    # print it leaving pending task to be executing.
    # But note two important things:
    # 1) You should guarantee pending task done before loop closed
    # 2) What if pending task will finish with error, is it ok?
    elif is_good_timeout:
        print('Timeout, but enought tasks done:')
        for t in tasks:
            if t.done():
                print(t.result())
    # Timeout and not enought tasks done,
    # let's just cancel all hanging:    
    elif is_bad_timeout:
        await cancel_and_retrieve(tasks)
        raise RuntimeError('Timeout and not enought tasks done')  # You probably want indicate fail
    # If any of tasks is finished with an exception,
    # we should probably cancel unfinished tasks,
    # await all tasks done and retrive all exceptions to prevent warnings
    # ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#detect-exceptions-never-consumed )
    elif is_exception:
        await cancel_and_retrieve(tasks)
        raise RuntimeError('Exception in one of tasks')  # You probably want indicate fail


async def cancel_and_retrieve(tasks):
    """
    Cancel all pending tasks, retrieve all exceptions
    ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#detect-exceptions-never-consumed )
    It's cleanup function if we don't want task being continued.
    """
    for t in tasks:
        if not t.done():
            t.cancel()
    await asyncio.wait(
        tasks, 
        return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED
    )
    for t in tasks:
        with suppress(Exception):
            await t


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:

        # If some tasks still pending (is_good_timeout case), 
        # let's kill them:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            cancel_and_retrieve(asyncio.Task.all_tasks())
        )

        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()
```

Comment: Lets use this logic for a second, lets say you're displaying stocks. There are 3 stocks.  You request for the price of the stock, but stock 2 is taking longer. Instead of waiting, we just display stock price 1 & 3.

Comment: @StandardCitizen if stock 2 arrives before 1 or 3, what we do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, lets say 2 arrival within the allowed time and entered into the database. While the 3rd is taking too long. Therefore, we'll return the request, but the 3rd process will stay open and carries out the job until completed. Hopefully, upon the refresh of the user, it will be done. Lets say these stocks are only opened once daily.

Comment: @StandardCitizen I updated answer adding complex example that contains different possible situations (vary `timeout` and `exception_in_2`) and different reactions to them. Please, read it carefully. I think it does what you need, but even if you have something other in mind - this example will show how to handle, probably, almost all common situations.

Comment: It might be a design related issue, as the trigger for the task to request data from the API and the page response should be independent of each other. Thank you for your help, I really really am grateful.

Comment: @StandardCitizen `trigger for the task to request data from the API and the page response should be independent` - once you created task with `asyncio.ensure_future` it's started. You can move all logic starting from `asyncio.wait` to separate coroutine and start this coroutine with `asyncio.ensure_future` also. In this case you'll be able to return response immediately.

Comment: Hey Mikhail, I want to thank you for helping me. It solved my problem, I wish you the best.